# How to redirect user after success login to admin dashboard in multisite of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, multisite

After successful login user redirect to home url but i want to redirect it to admin dashboard after successful login in wordpress. 
***Note:I use multisite network.*** Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for wordpress multisite. It will direct user roles and redirect to specific page.

```
function login_redirect_page( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            return get_site_url().'/wp-admin/';
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect_page', 10, 3 );
```

You can get the plugins on wordpress.org also.

Comment: my all users are subscribers. I would like to redirect to admin dashboard. I just paste above code in the end of functions.php but not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
function login_redirect_page( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            return get_site_url().'/wp-admin/';
        }
        if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles ) ) {
            return get_site_url().'/wp-admin/';
        }else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect_page', 10, 3 );
```